# Does Apple's Game Center check the app version is up to date before match making? If not, how should I do this?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I have a game for the iPhone that I would like to introduce matchmaking for.  However, thinking in advance, I don't want to make updates and have players that are not up to date matchmaking with other players.

Please tell me Apple's Game Center is smart enough, but if not, how should I prepare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use playerGroup to make sure that you are not getting players matched that have different app versions. Just convert your version to a unique integer (e.g. 1.2 becomes 102) and put it into the playerGroup property of your GKMatchRequest.

Then, only games with the same playerGroup (=version) get matched to each other.

Note that you don't really make sure that older versions are not matched among each other (which would be bad policy anyway) but you can at least prevent games between different versions.

For more info, see *Advanced Matchmaking Topics* in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Matchmaking/Matchmaking.html

Edit: Apple has recently added Multiplayer Compatibility in Game Center. Click on your app and set the versions this game is compatible with. This also works across game bundles now with game center groups.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is still a relevant question, though I implemented it my way above over a year ago :)

Can you tell me if there is a minimum OS version associated with this feature though or was it available fromt he start of game center?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Apple will do this for you so the best method I've come across is to keep a tiny txt file on your own server that you can check against.

Like so:

```
NSString *versionString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myurl.com/latestversion.txt"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

if(GAME_VERSION != [versionString floatValue])
{
  //the latest version did not match the game version
}
```